# Enable security for web Application deployed at webSphere

Tags: java, security, ejb, websphere-8

I have a web application using JSF and EJB deployed at webSphere server 8.5.5

I need to enable security that allow me to get the logged-in user at EJB by using this function:

```
private SessionContext getSessionContext()  {


        InitialContext icContext;
        try {
            icContext = new InitialContext();
            return (SessionContext) icContext.lookup("java:comp/EJBContext");
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    return null;
}
```

currently this function return "UNAUTHENTICATED".

Could you please advise start from where or any tutorial ?

Comment: What kind of realm do you want? The preparations needed depend on it.

Comment: The ways how to get an EJBContext : http://javahowto.blogspot.hu/2006/06/4-ways-to-get-ejbcontext-in-ejb-3.html And some tutorials on Java security : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/listtutorials/java/security/1

Comment: Thanks @The Bitman for your support, I want to apply Database realm

Comment: some tutorial for a (jdbc and others) realm setup : https://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/3.0.x/realm-howto.html

Comment: Please, Is there a one for webSphere server ?

Comment: Just use google serch "jdbc realm websphere" and found it : https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0709_vamsi/0709_vamsi.html

Comment: yes of course i already did that before posting my question, and that tutorial not that much detailed. Thanks for your help.